# Unit testing a DLL in c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dll

Say I have a MyDLL.dll which exports 2 classes: ClassA, ClassB. ClassB depends on ClassA.

Next, I create a unit test that references MyDLL.dll. I can easily test both ClassA and ClassB, but what if I want to mock ClassA in order to test ClassB on its own?

Basically, is it possible to either:

A) Only import specific classes of a DLL.

B) Redefine classes from an imported DLL.

Comment: How exactly is *depends on ClassA* implemented in code? If it's through composition, standard way would be to make classA implement an interface, say 'interfaceA', and make classB take e.g. an std::unique_ptr<interfaceA> as constructor parameter instead of using classA directly. Then when testing you pass a mock of interfaceA instead.

Comment: Yeah it's through composition. Using an interface would work but I would like to avoid having to change the original source code. Is there no other solution? I don't like the idea of modifying code that works JUST so I can test it.

Comment: Unit testing is easiest when you start it when you start the project so that you can think of how you would test as you design and code. Otherwise, I would expect needing some changes so that an existing project can be unit tested.

Comment: If your mocking framework supports mocking non-virtual methods you can use the same principle (pass instance in constructor) but you'd need less code changes. I really doubt there's another way: when B is compiled and then linked and has a classA member which isn't injected that is sort of set in stone, I doubt there's any portable way to fiddle with that. Doesn't matter if it's in a dll or not.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I was afraid there would be no other options, but it's nice to have a confirmation.